# How do I examine subview properties with IOS debugger

Tags: ios, debugging

The debugger window in Xcode shows you the values of local variables within the current scope (for instance if you are single stepping). But suppose I want to examine a property in a subview (for example, a UIScrollView instance/property such as self.scrollview.zoomScale)?

I have tried eyeballing underneath the "self" variable in the debugger window but cannot find the instantiated UIScrollView.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, on the debug window:

```
po self.scrollview.zoomScale
```

or in your case:

```
p self.scrollview.zoomScale
```

If nothing comes, just put a `NSLog` outputting the value of the zoomScale.

Comment: Thanks but I am specifically trying to avoid NSLog and harness the power of the debugger. But you got me pointed in the correct direction... in my case I had to use the backing-variable instance name (_scrollView) and had to cast it to the appropriate type, that is "p (float)[self._scrollView zoomScale]"

Comment: still, did it helped you? Sometimes I have problems and have to go with the NSLog, still, the debug window with the `po`command is **gold**

Comment: Weird... in particular zoomScale is only available in gdb with the getter method I noted in the comment above as opposed to dot notation. Dot notation works fine for other UIScrollView variables (e.g. p (float)self._scrollView._maximumZoomScale).